# Strip a section of an embed code with PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, embed, jwplayer

I'm trying to search JW Player embed codes like this one:

```
<iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/ewQYJ6zA-F6KYzWLn.html" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What I need to grab is the code right after `players/` which in this embed would be just `ewQYJ6zA`.

Anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search for players/ followed by one or more letters and numbers.

```
 <?php
    $string = '<iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/ewQYJ6zA-F6KYzWLn.html" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    preg_match( '~/players/([[a-zA-Z\d]+)~', $string, $matches );
    echo $matches[1];
?>
```

**Output**: 
 ewQYJ6zA

Answer (score 2):

This regex in PHP should do the trick:

```
preg_match('/players\/(.+)-/im', $codetomatch, $codeyouwant);
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bP0bJ3/1)

Comment: Ok, let me try it :)

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't worked correctly, but Emil had a different suggestion. I upvoted your comment for helping me anyways :)

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution you need. The solution I provided does work, you just have to take out the space between \ and /. I am a bit new to Stackoverflow and don't know how to keep Stackoverflow from stripping my code when it is published.

Comment: How would that work? Can you [show in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1oI5/1)? He wants to extract `ewQYJ6zA` only (:

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bP0bJ3/1
I really need to learn how to format answers better :-P

Comment: @RayLi updated your answer. please check if that's ok.